# Custom Validation Pattern in Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I have one custom validation function in provider. 
If user input non of these [A, B , C and /], return error.
Currently that function works fine.
In advance I want to check the following patterns(want to allow that patterns only)and non of that patterns, want to return error.

```php
A
C
B
A/B
A/C
A/C/B
A/B/C
C/A
C/B
C/A/B
C/B/A
B/A
B/C
B/A/C
B/C/A
```

```php
Validator::extend('capital_letter_abc_with_slash', function ($attribute, $value, $parameter, $validator) {
    return preg_match('/[ABC\/]/', $value) === 1;
});
```

Comment: Maybe  `'~^(?!.*([ABC]).*\1)[ABC](?:/[ABC]){0,2}$~'`?

Comment: `A/B` is there twice, `A/C` doesn't appear, is that a typo?

Comment: @kerbholz Yes, It is my fault, I updated it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your comment. It also works as correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex should be like this:

```php
preg_match('/^(?!.*(.)\/.*\1)[ABC](\/[ABC]){0,2}$/', $value);
```

These letters do **not repeat**.

For https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-regex

You can do something like this:

```php
Validator::make($parameter, [
    'abc' => 'regex:/^(?!.*(.)\/.*\1)[ABC](\/[ABC]){0,2}$/'
]);
```

You can test your regex here:
https://tsaikoga.github.io/it-tools/web/index.html#/regex-page

[image: Regex result]

Comment: for example, `A/A/A` will be valid. as far i understood, @hayato needs to prevent such values

Comment: @TsaiKoga thanks for your suggestion. as Roman said A/A/A is not OK for me

Comment: I have fix my answer. This works fine to me.@Hayato

Answer (score -1):

If you have set of allowed values, the simplest way in my opinion is put it into array and traverse it in validation rule:

```php
Validator::extend('abc', function ($attribute, $value, $parameter, $validator) {
    $allowedPatterns = [
        'A',
        'C',
        'B',
        'A/B',
        'A/B',
        'A/C/B',
        'A/B/C',
        'C/A',
        'C/B',
        'C/A/B',
        'C/B/A',
        'B/A',
        'B/C',
        'B/A/C',
        'B/C/A',
    ];

    foreach ($allowedPatterns as $pattern) {
        if ($value === $pattern) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
});
```

You can store that array in config, in the model, wherever you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also appreciate your solution. This time let me use the validation with pattern. :)